# Adaptive Card Conditional

Tags: botframework, adaptive-cards

I'm trying to prepare a card that brings 2 cities of the selected country in a single page, but I can't set the conditions.

I shared the adaptive card designer image and json format below.

I want to determine the sub-selections according to the selections, I will use the conditional structure for this, but I had a big problem with editing, none of the methods I tried worked. Thank you in advance for your suggestions and informative messages.

[image: Adaptive Card Designer]

```
{
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "version": "1.3",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "Input.ChoiceSet",
            "id": "country",
            "title": "Select a country",
            "choices": [
                {
                    "title": "Italy",
                    "value": "italy"
                },
                {
                    "title": "England",
                    "value": "england"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "Input.ChoiceSet",
            "id": "city",
            "title": "Select a city",
            "country.value":"italy",
            "choices": [
                {
                    "title": "Roma",
                    "value": "roma",
                    "$when": "{{country.value} == 'italy'}"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Milano",
                    "value": "milano",
                    "when": "{{country.value == 'italy'}}"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Manchester",
                    "value": "manchester",
                    "when": "{{country.value == 'england'}}"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Liverpool",
                    "value": "liverpool",
                    "when": "{{country.value == 'england'}}"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "actions": [
        {
            "type": "Action.Submit",
            "title": "Submit"
        }
    ]
}
```